# How can I get write access to my usb drives?

Tags: permissions, arch-linux, filesystems, nautilus, readonly

I have trouble writing to external drives. They are monuted automatically in Nautilus, but I cannot copy anything there ('Paste' and 'create Folder' are just greyed out).

Does anyone have ideas what could be wrong?

The drive is named 4E29-64CA (but other drives behave the same) and I get the following error when trying to do anything to it:

```
/run/media/username/4E29-64CA $ touch foo
touch: cannot touch ‘foo’: Read-only file system
```

As root same error:

```
/run/media/username/4E29-64CA $ sudo touch foo
[sudo] password for username: 
touch: cannot touch ‘foo’: Read-only file system
```

`ls -l /run/media/username` gives the following:

```
drwx------ 6 xxxxxxxx users 4096 Jan  1  1970 4E29-64CA
```

So it seems I have the right permissions.

**Further relevant(?) stuff:**

Output of `mount`:

```
$ mount | grep 4E29
/dev/sdc1 on /run/media/username/4E29-64CA type vfat (ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=1000,gid=100,fmask=0022,dmask=0077,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,showexec,utf8,flush,errors=remount-ro,uhelper=udisks2)
$ mount | grep 1000
tmpfs on /run/user/1000 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=372244k,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=100)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1000/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=100)
```

Groups I am in:

```
$ groups
audio storage users networkmanager sudoers
```

From `/usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.freedesktop.udisks2.policy`:

```
<action id="org.freedesktop.udisks2.filesystem-mount">
    <description>Mount a filesystem</description>
    <message>Authentication is required to mount the filesystem</message>
    <defaults>
          <allow_any>auth_admin</allow_any>
          <allow_inactive>auth_admin</allow_inactive>
          <allow_active>yes</allow_active>
    </defaults>
</action>
```

Answer (score 1):

First I think the problem is mounting the USB in the `/run` directory.

Try this:

create a mounting point on `/media`. Let's named myUsb

```
sudo mkdir /media/myUsb
```

Try to remount with `rw` permissions

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw /partition/identifier /mount/point
```

Then in your case the command will be

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw /dev/sdc1 /media/myUsb
```